# Running separate CakePHP apps on different domains

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, wampserver

---

I am trying to install two independent, separate CakePHP applications using different databases and domains.

The goal is to be able to access these sites just by typing in the different domain names, i.e. instead of typing `localhost/controllerName` **ideally** would be `client1/controllerName` and `client2/controllerName` or just anything to differentiate the names and access to the apps.

I am using **WAMPSERVER** (it is Apache 2.2.17 + mySQL + PHP + phpMyAdmin).

I have already found some tutorials but part of them is just messy, part of them doesn't really refer to my case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

### Setup multiple virtual hosts

To do what you ask all you need to do is setup multiple virtual hosts i.e. in your apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName client1.dev
    DocumentRoot /my/apps/are/here/client1/webroot
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName client2.dev
    DocumentRoot /my/apps/are/here/client2/webroot
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll also need to edit your hosts file or router so that it contains:

```
127.0.0.1 client1.dev client2.dev
```

With that, http://client1.dev and http://client2.dev will both point at your local machine and each domain map to a different application.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this helps:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/05/29/working-with-domains-locally/

I use WAMP too